# Can a Jbutton (ActionListener) start a static Method?

Tags: javascript, java, jbutton, actionlistener, static-methods

Im currently coding a Q&A Program, coincidentally called "Jarvis" (Iron Man AI).
The program isnt going to be that complex, so it just answers a few questions and will do simple things like start a song or open the explorer when I write a specific sentence.
I'm the complete opposite of a experienced Java-Programmer,
 so I wrote all the important code into a JButton-Actionlistener started Method,
 the rest of the code is just for design of the application window.
My problem right now is, that my Method,
`public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0)`
which is started by my JButton ActionListener is just a "public void" Method, so that Im verry limited in my Code.
For example: for some things you need to have a
`public static void main (String[]args)`
method,
but i dont know how to activate such a method by my actionlistener,
so when I try to start one of these with my actionlistener, there are errors everywhere and even the qickfix removed the "static" from the method. 
(If you have any suggestions of making it more efficient, please let me know!)
 
However, here is my "Program" so far:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.SystemColor;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import java.awt.Color;
import javazoom.jl.player.Player;
import java.io.FileInputStream;


public class JarvisOS {

    JFrame JarvisOS;
    private JTextField Input;
    private JTextField Output;
    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    JarvisOS window = new JarvisOS();
                    window.JarvisOS.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public JarvisOS() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        JarvisOS = new JFrame();
        JarvisOS.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        JarvisOS.getContentPane().setBackground(SystemColor.window);
        JarvisOS.setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("E:\\Programme\\Eclipse\\JarvisOS\\JarvisICO.png"));
        JarvisOS.setTitle("JarvisOS");
        JarvisOS.setBounds(100, 100, 1932, 1368);
        JarvisOS.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH); 
        JarvisOS.setVisible(true);
        JarvisOS.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JButton Send = new JButton("");
        Send.setIcon(new ImageIcon("E:\\Programme\\Eclipse\\JarvisOS\\SendButton.png"));
        Send.setRolloverIcon(new ImageIcon("E:\\Programme\\Eclipse\\JarvisOS\\SendButton Activated.png"));
        Send.setBounds(1092, 481, 130, 130);
        Send.setForeground(SystemColor.window);
        Send.setBorderPainted(false);
        JarvisOS.getRootPane().setDefaultButton(Send);
        Send.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) { 


                String Text = Input.getText();


                if(Text.equalsIgnoreCase("Hello"))  {
                     Output.setText("Hi");  }

                else if(Text.equalsIgnoreCase("What are you doing"))    {
                     Output.setText("Nothing Special"); }           

                else if(Text.equalsIgnoreCase("Do you like me?"))   {
                     Output.setText("Yes"); }   



                else{
                     Output.setText("Cant understand that!");}

            }
        });
        JarvisOS.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        Send.setFont(new Font("Arial Black", Font.PLAIN, 16));
        Send.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        JarvisOS.getContentPane().add(Send);

        JButton RecVoice = new JButton("");
        RecVoice.setToolTipText("Record Voice");
        RecVoice.setSelectedIcon(new ImageIcon("E:\\Programme\\Eclipse\\JarvisOS\\JarvisOSLogo.png"));
        RecVoice.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        RecVoice.setIcon(new ImageIcon("E:\\Programme\\Eclipse\\JarvisOS\\Record Button.png"));
        RecVoice.setRolloverIcon(new ImageIcon("E:\\Programme\\Eclipse\\JarvisOS\\Record Button Animated.gif"));
        RecVoice.setBounds(1598, 698, 296, 298);
        RecVoice.setBorderPainted(false);
        JarvisOS.getContentPane().add(RecVoice);

        Input = new JTextField();
        Input.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
        Input.setBounds(230, 445, 824, 68);
        Input.setForeground(SystemColor.window);
        Input.setToolTipText("");
        Input.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 40));
        Input.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        JarvisOS.getContentPane().add(Input);
        Input.setColumns(10);

        Output = new JTextField();
        Output.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
        Output.setBounds(230, 584, 824, 68);
        Output.setForeground(SystemColor.window);
        Output.setEditable(false);
        Output.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 30));
        Output.setColumns(10);
        Output.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        JarvisOS.getContentPane().add(Output);

        JLabel Circle = new JLabel("");
        Circle.setIcon(new ImageIcon("E:\\Programme\\Eclipse\\JarvisOS\\Circle.gif"));
        Circle.setBounds(1756, 43, 150, 150);
        JarvisOS.getContentPane().add(Circle);

        JLabel JarvisBackground = new JLabel("");
        JarvisBackground.setBounds(0, 0, 1920, 1080);
        JarvisBackground.setIcon(new ImageIcon("E:\\Programme\\Eclipse\\JarvisOS\\Jarvis Background.png"));
        JarvisOS.getContentPane().add(JarvisBackground);
    }
}
```

Best regards

Comment: `"Can a Jbutton (ActionListener) start a static Method?"` -- answer, "YES"

Comment: Also, please understand that this is a site where questions and answers that can help all are presented. In order for this question to help future users we ask that you post **all** pertinent information here with your question and not in links. Also, please understand that all who help here are volunteers, and we much appreciate your making it as easy as possible to understand your question, including not making us go to outside sites for information.

Comment: I've removed your link and replaced it with the containing code.

Comment: Also, your problems have nothing to do with ActionListener not being static, but likely due to your trying to obtain instance references, either to a field or a method, from a static context. If you need help with this, show your actual and complete error message with your question and indicate which line(s) are causing it.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Im new to this site :)

Comment: This is a very bad idea: `public class JarvisOS {   JFrame JarvisOS;` Do not give your fields the same name as your class. Also follow Java naming conventions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted above, you can call a static method from both a static and non-static context.

However, the method

```
public static void main (String[] args)
```

is the entry point to your program (as also noted by the comment above it), so it is unlikely you would want to call that from the action handler of your button. It will be called automatically when you launch java with your JarvisOS class as target (or run from your IDE, which I assume you use since you have quick fixes).

The signature of the main method is fixed, so whatever the quick fix suggests, do not remove the static keyword as that will prevent you from starting your program.

You will need to be more specific about the other "errors everywhere".

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could do

```
myButton.addActionListener(e -> myStaticMethod());
```

Good luck!